# OSX Activity monitor Network bandwidth period

Tags: macos

I found this little table in OSX Activity Monitor in Network tab

[image: bandwidth stats]

I'd like to ask what's the period used as it's not written anywhere. Is it data downloaded/uploaded per 30 days, 90 days 7 days...?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These show the totals since the primary interface was brought up.  You can test this by observing the counter as you disconnect your primary interface, wait for a short while, then plug it back in.

Primary interface can be determined by looking in your Network Preferences or at a terminal with: `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder`

See also: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly confident that's just a display of the interface network counter, which will display the amount of data **since the interface was brought "up"**; probably since the last reboot in most cases, unless you specifically disconnected the network interface.